# What dependency is missing when I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/client/RxInvokerProvider error?

Tags: java, maven

I have a small project where for testing purposes I execute my jersey 2 client by unit test. But, unfortunately, I got the error attached. I don't know what dependency still missing. At the moment Jersey's webpage is down due to maintenance.

I put the same  Relevant part of pom.xml, test code and tested code also attached.

```
public void getWorkItems() {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 2000);
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);    

        WebTarget webTarget = client.target("https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=100,101&api-version=1.0");

        Invocation.Builder inBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        Response response = inBuilder.get();    
    }


public class WorkItemTests {

    @Test
    public void Vsts_Test() {
        WorkItems workItems = new WorkItems();
        workItems.getWorkItems();
    }        
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>stuff</groupId>
            <artifactId>Vsts.Connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/client/RxInvokerProvider

    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getJaxRsProviderInterfaces(Providers.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.<clinit>(Providers.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.AbstractRuntimeDelegate.<init>(AbstractRuntimeDelegate.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl.<init>(RuntimeDelegateImpl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:118)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:166)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:135)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:120)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.newInstance(UriBuilder.java:95)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.<init>(JerseyWebTarget.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:76)
    at WorkItems.getWorkItems(WorkItems.java:24)
    at WorkItemTests.Vsts_Test2(WorkItemTests.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.client.RxInvokerProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 42 more


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: Have you tried to google <class name>jar?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-m01</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Eventually, `<version>2.1-m07</version>` is the winner. Please edit your answer and I'll accept it! Could you provide some explanation why these differences between packages?

Comment: `javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar` does NOT have it.

Comment: ...in fact, mvnrepository.com's hosting of new versions of that jar 2.0 is completely broken, which is the main reason for the suffering I and the OP are going through.

Comment: Since Aug 2017, `<version>2.1</version>` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue while starting up the tomcat 7 server using Restful Web Services with Hibernate and it was resolved by adding the following dependency to the pom.xml in my project.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

As it will download all the neccessary jars required for the project.I hope it will help.